# Why isn't an Acid-base titration curve linear?

Tags: acid-base, titration

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why is a acid-base titration curve not linear? As you add more acid solution to a basic solution, shouldn't the pH of the basic solution slowly go up in proportion to the amount of acid added? Why is there such a sudden increase?

Comment: @DGS if you just added acid to a non-reactive solvent it would be linear, but if you are titrating a base then no.